# Edit profile: birthday should be “date of birth”

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

This field should be “date of birth”. Also, could you show an optional dropdown calendar on that field?

[image: Why “Birthday”?]

Comment: Why? No seriously, why?

Comment: No, it should be Date of Birth :)

Comment: Use a dictionary.  It means both the the anniversary and the day of birth.  The cue makes it obvious which one is meant.

Comment: Asking for the birthday or the birthdate (when it's clear in which format you want the answer) gets the same answer.

Comment: @Uphill Luge: When I have the choice between a canonical term and another term that not everyone may understand at once, I would choose the first one. While “birthday” is correct a [dictonary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/birthday) will say that “birth date” is more commonly used.

Comment: I'm more curious about how the optional drop down calendar helps.  A person would either have to type in their birth month and year to get to the correct calendar page, or scroll through anywhere from 240 to 720 calendar pages to get to the month and year of their birth.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**This is a pointless change.**

While we are at it, on that same page we could clarify some other things:

`Email` should be `Email Address`, otherwise someone may just put in "Yes, please!" or "Send me spam!"

`Website` should probably be `Website Address` or `Website URL` otherwise I could just put "JNK's Blog" which still meets the stated requirement without providing a link or anything useful.

`Location` should probably be `Geographic Location` or `City/Region/Country` since accurate answers could include:

- At my desk
- At work
- At home
- Sea level
- On a plane
- On a boat
- At the beach

If someone has difficulty figuring out what is needed in the "Birthday" field when there is a very clear formatting prompt there (`YYYY/MM/DD`) then they may need more help than the SE network can provide.

Comment: Is “Sea level” a location? I would call it an altitude.

Comment: Location is extremely general.  I think `Sea Level` would work, so would `Milky Way`, `Earth`, `Above Ground`, etc.

Comment: That's not what dictionaries say (Uphill Luge's comment above suggested using them). They say “lo·ca·tion/lōˈkāSHən/:  A particular place or position.” Never mind, this is irrelevant to my original question :)

Comment: @Benoit ___Irrelevant?___ Get into the spirit of meta-discussion!

Comment: helping you towards the reversal badge.